# String parser logic in java

Tags: java, php, arraylist, hashmap, javaparser

I have a string like below which can grow further with few more AND/OR/NOT condition but maintains the syntax.

```
String string = "apple,mango,name(
        AND(
              OR(
                  gender[male,female],
                  county[USA,India]
              ),
             language[spanish,english],
             education[masters,bachelors],
             NOT(
                 education[Phd]
             )
        )
     ),orange"
```

Need to parse this string. partially successful to convert this string as JSON object. But couldn't do it completely.

Comment: ok, good. best of luck.

Comment: Think about using JSON or other data formats if possible. Try not to reinvent the wheel. Can you change the input data? What are your efforts so far?

Comment: @Ben, I was having difficulties to parse itself. With the hint of JSON, which seems to be easy. Will post the complete code once am done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easliy convert this to a rough json string. A quick sample would be

```
String json = "{"+string.replace("(",":{").replace("[",":[").replace(")","}")+"}";
```

Of course you would need to add to this to make it a valid json by inserting quotes as necessary " or ' .

Once you have JSOn you would be able to easily convert this to a java object. Check Jackson or GSON libraries.

Comment: thank you. I am working on this.